# Moxtra invite users to existing binder SSO

Tags: javascript, chat

I am using the Moxtra JavaScript SDK to implement the timeline functionality in my app.

I want to create a central binder for my user groups and got everything working except the inviting of another of my users to a existing binder.

```js
function getTimeline(access_token, binderID) {
    var options = {
        access_token: access_token,
        binder_id: binderID,
        iframe: true,
        tagid4iframe: "container",
        iframewidth: "920px",
        iframeheight: "650px",
        autostart_meet: true,
        autostart_note: true,
        extension: {"show_dialogs": {"meet_invite": true}},
        start_timeline: function (event) {
            alert("Timeline started session Id: " + event.session_id + " binder id: " + event.binder_id);
        },
        view_binder: function (event) {
            alert("Binder switched session Id: " + event.session_id + " binder id: " + event.binder_id);
        },
        invite_member: function (event) {
          var userID = UNIQUEUSERID
            alert("Invite member into binder Id: " + event.binder_id);
            console.log(Moxtra.baseUrl + "/" + event.binder_id + "/inviteuser");
            var postData = {
                "users": [
                    {
                        "user": {
                            "unique_id": userID
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "message": "Custom message to join this conversation..."
            };
            $.ajax("https://api.moxtra.com/v1/" + event.binder_id + "/inviteuser", {
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        },
        start_meet: function (event) {
            alert("Meet started session key: " + event.session_key + " session id: " + event.session_id);
        },
        end_meet: function (event) {
            alert("Meet end event");
        },
        save_meet: function (event) {
            alert("Meet saved on binder: " + event.binder_id);
        },
        start_note: function (event) {
            alert("session key: " + event.session_key + " session id: " + event.session_id);
        },
        save_note: function (event) {
            alert("Note saved on binder: " + event.destination_binder_id);
        },
        cancel_note: function (event) {
            alert("Note cancelled");
        },
        error: function (event) {
            alert("Timeline error code: " + event.error_code + " error message: " + event.error_message);
        }
    };
    Moxtra.timeline(options);
}
```

as you can see the getTimeline request handles the invite_member event, there is no build in invite user to chat/binder so I can't use that.

Seeming that the SDK calls the REST API I am using that myself to add the invite user functionality. But when I test the request with their API console I get a error saying that the group is not found. 
I assign the users to the same group so that shouldn't be the issue and tried to add a user via my unique-id and the moxtra unique-id. What am I doing wrong? Or what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the binder that you are trying to add users (using their unique id) was also created by an user who got created in Moxtra using unique_id method. In that case using the REST API to add team member is the right approach to add additional users to the binder.

When you use the API console, you will be using the access token generated through your moxtra email account. It cannot be used with the binder that you created through the unique_id method.

Based on the error that you mentioned above it looks like either the user who you are trying to add or the user who created the binder are not in the same group. Please make sure both the users are provisioned using the same SSO method.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it with my SSO token instead of the API console ;)

Comment: Your answer helped me allot, I was able to manipulate your console a bit and send my own access token along to invite a user to one of my SSO user binders and from there I will be able to formulate the right event handlers. (btw I can't upvote this solution due to my lack of reputation)